# How to make a physical wall using cocos2d / chipmunk?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, game-physics, chipmunk

How to make a physical wall using cocos2d / chipmunk ? So that sprite just can not go throught another one sprite(wall)? Sorry,if it's already answered somewhere, I can't find any information for beginners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from cocos2d/chipmunk template. Your sprite should be on chipmunk body, to get that change position of sprite to position of body in your update method.

```
CGSize s = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

_space = cpSpaceNew();

cpSpaceSetGravity( _space, cpv(0, -100) );

//
// rogue shapes
// We have to free them manually
//
// bottom
_walls[0] = cpSegmentShapeNew( _space->staticBody, cpv(0,0), cpv(s.width,0), 0.0f);

// top
_walls[1] = cpSegmentShapeNew( _space->staticBody, cpv(0,s.height), cpv(s.width,s.height), 0.0f);

// left
_walls[2] = cpSegmentShapeNew( _space->staticBody, cpv(0,0), cpv(0,s.height), 0.0f);

// right
_walls[3] = cpSegmentShapeNew( _space->staticBody, cpv(s.width,0), cpv(s.width,s.height), 0.0f);

for( int i=0;i<4;i++) {
    cpShapeSetElasticity( _walls[i], 1.0f );
    cpShapeSetFriction( _walls[i], 1.0f );
    cpSpaceAddStaticShape(_space, _walls[i] );
}
```